# Transferir arquivos do server para o cliente??

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

Estou gerando um PDF no servidor NodeJS e quando ele estiver pronto quero que ele seja enviado para o cliente e seja baixado, tudo isso através de uma requisição GET. O arquivo será gerado no servidor, armazenado em um endereço específico e depois será devolvido na requisição GET, ou também pode ser enviado através de um click em um link. Tudo o que eu preciso é descobrir como enviar esse PDF para o cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você esteja usando o servidor express, use o `res.download`

Ele transfere o arquivo no caminho como um `attachment`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    

router.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    var filePath = "/Users/meuuser/PDFs"; //caminho do arquivo completo
    var fileName = "report.pdf"; // O nome padrão que o browser vai usar pra fazer download

    res.download(filePath, fileName);    
});
```

Obs.: Existe o `res.attachment`, mas se voce utilizar, ele irá definir o header `Content-Disposition` como "attachment" e isso irá fazer com que o navegador entenda que ele deve ser visto como um anexo, e não uma webpage. Quando você usa o `res.download`, ele *transfere* o arquivo como anexo, então geralmente os navegadores irão considerar baixar o arquivo.

Referencia: Documentação express [res.download](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download).